# Obter Código ID da URL e inserir no JS

Tags: jquery, ajax

Como pegar o código `galeria` da *url* `http://URL/galerias.php?galeria=casais` e colocar no js?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#conteudo').load('galeria.php?galeria='prodId'', 
      function(){
        $('#gallery a').lightBox();
      }
    );
});
```

Comment: Não entendi o que seu exemplo de código tem a ver com a pergunta: se você já tem um valor pra `prodId`, basta usa-lo. Mas se você não tem, e quer recuperar da URL *atual*, então pra que você vai fazer uma chamada com `load` pra mesma URL? Por favor explique melhor qual é sua pergunta.

Comment: @mgibsonbr de uma conferida em meu site

http://rafaelaalves.com/pjax/

quando entro na galeria ele lista todas as galerias, mas quando seleciono alguma ele abre a mesma mas quando clico para abrir uma foto via lightbox ele abre a imagem normalmente, e conseguindo colocar o codigo recebido pela URL no local de `prodId` consigo fazer uma segunda pagina que faça essa função ser exibida

Comment: Continuo sem entender... De todo modo, já experimentou usar `window.location.search`? Procure por `galeria=` nesse texto, logo em seguida vai estar o seu valor (seguido de um `&`, de um `#` ou do fim da string). P.S. Abri seu site no Chrome, e se eu clico numa galeria, ele vai pra galeria certa...

Answer (score 1):

Quando tens um URL deste tipo:

```
http://URL/galerias.php?galeria=casais
```

a parte `?galeria=casais` chama-se *query string* e podes ir buscar com [`window.location.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils/search) no formato *string*. Agora precisas só retirar de lá essa info, por exemplo via regex. Se a *chave* do *valor* que procuras é `galeria` podes fazer assim:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var query = window.location.search;
    var match = window.location.search.match(/galeria=(\w+)/);
    var galeria = match && match[1];
    $('#conteudo').load('galeria.php?galeria=' + prodId, 
      function(){
        $('#gallery a').lightBox();
      }
    );
});
```

A razão de eu fazer primeiro `match` e depois `galeria = match && match[1];` é porque no caso de não haver *match* evitar dar erro ao acessar `match[1]`, pois se não houver *match* o método vai dar `null` e não uma `array`.

Comment: Ola Sergio desculpe nao explicar corretamente mas eu gostaria que a query string ?galeria=casais o valor casais ficasse no lugar de 'prodId', pois ela pode conter o valor ?galeria=casais | ?galeria=crianças | ?galeria=idosos e assim por diante

Comment: @CristianoCardosoSilva então queres redirecionar a página? Nesse caso basta: `window.location.search = window.location.search.replace(/galeria=(\w+)/, prodId);`

Comment: nao e bem redirecionar, mas sim que ela abra dentro de uma DIV

Comment: @CristianoCardosoSilva a ver se eu entendo então: Esse valor ?galeria=casais | ?galeria=crianças | ?galeria=idosos vem de onde? e quando o tiveres queres fazer `.load()` com esse url certo? (repara que na minha resposta tinha um erro copiado do teu código, onde faltava um `+` para concatenar a variável aqui: `.load('galeria.php?galeria='prodId''` (na resposta já está certo agora).

Comment: nao e bem redirecionar, mas sim que ela abra o conteudo dentro de uma DIV
tipo tenho a seguinte DIV

 <div id="conteudo"></div>

quando abro a pagina '/galeria/galerias.php?galeria=gravidas' desejo que dentro da div conteudo ela carrega para mim a pagina '/galeria/galeria.php?galeria=gravidas
pois da forma que esta quando acesso a pagina '/galeria/galerias.php?galeria=gravidas' a primeira foto que abro ela carrega direto na URL '/galeria/gravidas/0IMG_5260.jpg' sendo que era para abrir em uma lightbox mas quando vo ao navegador e mando voltar ja funciona a lightbox normalmente

Comment: de uma olhada (http://rafaelaalves.com/galeria)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode recuperar pelo php

```
$galeria = $_GET['galeria'];
```

depois criar um input do tipo hidden no html

```
<input type="hidden" id="galeria" value="<?php echo $galeria; ?>">
```

e por fim recuperar no javascript

```
var proId = $('#galeria').val();
```

É um jeito que pensei a primeiro momento, acredito eu que pode existir algo melhor.

*obs.: eu não cheguei a testar*

Comment: Eu não entendi o que você quiz fazer com aquele código no javascript que vc colocou, de qualquer forma elaborei uma resposta de acordo com o titulo da pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Cara, o jeito que você está fazendo tudo isto me parece bem complicado, porque você não tenta simplificar?

Para saber qual galeria foi selecionada você poderia fazer algo assim:

```
<ol>
    <li class="galeria" data-galeria="casais">Casais</li>
    <li class="galeria" data-galeria="gravidas">Gr&aacute;vidas</li>
    <li class="galeria" data-galeria="criancas">Crian&ccedil;as</li>
    <li class="galeria" data-galeria="bebes">Beb&ecirc;s</li>
</ol>
```

E para carregar as galerias que forem sendo clicadas você faz o seguinte:

```
$(document).on("click", ".galeria", function()
{
    var galeriaSelecionada = $(this).data("galeria");

    $('#conteudo').load('galeria.php?galeria=' + galeriaSelecionada, 
      function(){
        $('#gallery a').lightBox();
      }
    );
});
```